# Figuring out a proper way to read in data

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, message, coordinate-systems

https://drive.google.com/a/navasotaisd.org/file/d/0B3eMFMufj6uVaVNpR0JYNnV4OTQ/view

Okay, so the problem above asks that you read in a file with a message and, using and x, y coordinate system, find the characters being read in and print out the character of that index value. I honestly have tried multiple solutions with making and array of arraylists, a arraylist of arraylists and many other failed data structures. All I need to know, is how would go about reading in the message so that I can search for it?

```
File f = new File("cipher.in");
    f.createNewFile();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    int numOfLines = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList();
    String code = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++) {
        code = scan.nextLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < code.length(); j++) {
            list.add(code.charAt(j));
        }
    }
    int index = 0;
    char[][] matrix = new char[(int)(list.size())][(int)(list.size())];
    for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
            matrix[r][c] = list.get(index);
            index++;
            if(index>=list.size())
                index--;
        }
    }
```

Sorry if this problem is a bit long. It's for my class I need to turn this problem in to be able to make a 100 in the gradebook. I'm just utterly stuck and frustrated.

Comment: _"I honestly have tried multiple solutions..."_ show us that

Comment: So far I'm not concerned about the searching part, I'm focused on more of just getting the data into a proper data structure so that I can work with it better...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a hash table to store the data. You will be able to search for it later on.

Answer (score 0):

The key fits quite nicely into a two-dimensional charcter array (char[][]). I would consider reading the first line (which specifies the number of lines on the key (rows of the array), and then construct the array. You have a constraint defined that a row can be no longer than 100 characters long so you can now define the complete "map".

After that i would read each line of the key, use an operator as charAt(index) and fill the map.

From there you have a very convenient structure to lookup the messages in the next part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out , this is you code with changes and comments so that you can understand the changes and the way this code works based on the instruction in your link, I did not try to compile it, so if it has any compilation errors try to fix them.  I kept your code and commented out the items that are not needed so that you can look at the differences,

```
File f = new File("cipher.in");
    //f.createNewFile();           //*  you are overwriting the file here
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
    int numOfLines = scan.nextInt();
    //str = scan.nextLine();      //* you just skipped one line from the numOfLInes
    //ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList();  //* this does not help, you need to index into the line number, char index
    TreeMap charMap = new TreeMap();                //* use this to map the line number to a char array
    String code = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++) {
        strubg code = scan.nextLine();
        charMap.put(i, code.toCharArray());         //* map the line number with the char array of each line
        //for (int j = 0; j < code.length(); j++) {
        //    list.add(code.charAt(j));
        //}
    }
    int numOfMessageLines = scan.nextInt();      //* get the number of message lines next  
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMessageLines; i++) {
      string  str = scan.nextLine();
      string[] pairs = str.split(" ");      //* each line has several key pairs for line number char number seprated by spaces
      ArrayList<char> list = new ArrayList();  //* this does not help, you need to index into the line number, char index
      for(int j=0; j<pairs.length; j++)
      {
        string[] st = pairs[j].trim().split(",");  //* example 2,13 indicate line 2 character 13 non zero indexed
        int lineNum = Integer.parse(st[0]) - 1;    //* zero indexed line number since we stored the lines in zero index map
        int charNum = Integer.parse(st[1]) - 1;    //* zero indexed char number since we stored the char array in zero indexed array
        char[] chars = charMap.get(lineNum);       //* get the char array for this line number
        char c = chars[charNum];                   //* get the character for the first message
        list.add(c);
      }  
      String message = new String(list.toArray());   //* construct the message from the char array
      System.out.println(message);
    }

    //int index = 0;
    //char[][] matrix = new char[(int)(list.size())][(int)(list.size())];
    //for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
    //    for (int c = 0; c < matrix[r].length; c++) {
    //        matrix[r][c] = list.get(index);
    //        index++;
    //        if(index>=list.size())
    //            index--;
    //    }
    //}
```